# Binding values in a @Html.ListBoxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm newbies with the language asp.net and I have some difficulties to understand how works the `@Html.ListBoxFor` ( even if I read the doc ).

In my case I have this:

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.groupe.Permissions, new SelectList(Model.permissionList,"Name"))
```

`model.groupe.Permissions` is an empty list of permission and `Model.permissionList` a list of permission.

I want to create a multiple select list and foreach option have `Id = permission.id` and `value = permission.Name`

How can I do something like that:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.groupe.Permissions, new SelectList(Model.permissionList, id ="Id", value = "Name"))
```

here permissionList :

```
 public List<Permission> permissionList { get; set; }
```

and Permission :

```
public class Permission
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: it should work with `Model.permissionList, "Id", "Name"`

Comment: You cannot bind a `<select multiple>` to a collection of complex objects. Property `Permissions` needs to be IEnumerable<long>` and its `@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.groupe.Permissions, new SelectList(Model.permissionList, "Id", "Name"))` in the view (but `permissionList` should be `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and you generate the `SelectList` in the controller), not the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this hope this helps:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.groupe.Permissions, new MultiSelectList(Model.permissionList, "Id", "Name"))
```

Comment: Nop :( , doesn't recognize id and value

Comment: My bad edited my answer, also make sure model.groupe.Permissions is an array of same type as ID in Model.PermissionList

Comment: I obtain this <li class="active"><span><input type="checkbox"><label></label>AccessAdminPage</span></li> as I obtain before, but I haven't the id :/

Comment: Pls post your PermissionList and Permissions classes in your question. Thanks

Comment: Pls post all classes your Groupe.Permissions too. I just tried at my end same code in answer works for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144089/discussion-between-user3250-and-nathan-meunier).